# How can i change mail recipients based on selection?

Tags: html, mailto

I'm a solid newbie on this so it might not be pretty.  I had a series of inputs that i want to send through an email.  The email should change based on the option value selection.  I figured out how to set the mailto to a fixed email but i would like that to change emails based on location.

Im not sure what else to try

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>New Product Purchase Request Form</h2>

<form action="mailto:email@company.com?subject=New Product Purchase Request" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
Storeoom:<br>
<select name="Storeroom">
  <option value="Storeroom1">Storeroom1</option>
  <option value="Storeroom2">Storeroom2</option>
</select><br>
Requested By:<br>
<input type="text" name="Requested By:"><br>
Request Date:<br>
<input type="date" name="Request Date:"><br>
Product Name: <br>
<input type="text" name="Product Name:" size="50"><br>
Model/Part#: <br>
<input type="text" name="Model/Part#"><br>
Quantity: <br>
<input type="number" name="QTY:"><br>
Comment:<br>
<input type="text" name="comment" size="50"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Im hoping to see the email pass to the "mailto" based on the Storoom selection

Storeroom1 = email123@company.com
Storeroom2 - emailABC@company.com

Answer (score 0):

Your tags are just html and mailto, (so if those are the limits) then you have to have separate forms for each destination.

If you can use javascript, then you could have the browser update the destination based on a radio-button selection.

If this is customer facing, (or on the Internet) then you should probably be setting the email address server-side using something like [nms-FormMail](http://nms-cgi.sourceforge.net/scripts.shtml)